# Install OpenSuse on windows 7 without formatting it

Tags: windows, system-installation, opensuse, wubi

I have a netbook and I want to install `OpenSuse` on my Windows 7 just like installing Ubuntu in Windows 7 using `wubi`.

Is there a software like `wubi` for `OpenSuse` to install it without losing Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of, but you can always install OpenSuse (or any other Linux distro) on dual boot.  In this way you can choose at boot whether to run Linux or Windows.  You won't lose your Windows installation.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that or just write the steps to install opensueue on windows?

Comment: http://opensuse-guide.org/installation.php

Answer (score 0):

I run FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Windows 10 and several versions of Linux in VirtualBox on my Windows laptop.

https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: I don't want want to use virtualbox to install it. I want to install opensuse inside windows and i can delete by uninstalling it just like wubi for ubuntu.

Comment: That has to be horribly slow and you have to have a huge hdd for that.

Comment: Of course it's not slow, why would it be? CPU is hardly ever a problem with virtualization. As for storage, the Windows 10 VM is biggest by far at 24 GB. Running a bunch of VMs on a laptop hasn't been a problem for years.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try VMware player or VMware Workstation.

[VMware Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/4_0)

Answer (score 0):

See detailed documentation https://activedoc.opensuse.org/book/opensuse-reference/chapter-1-installation-with-yast openSUSE has little helping tool to boot installation media from Windows and the installer can resize Windows partition (although backup is highly recommended, of course).

Uninstalling is little bit more work. Probably the easiest would be to go to system tools in Windows, destroy openSUSE disk partition and enlarge Windows partition.